# how to convert uint64 to hexadecimal

Tags: python, hex, uint64

I wonder how I can convert an unsigned integer 64bit to the hexadecimal?

I have the value as '65536L' and what I am expected is '0x0000000000010000'.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Stringformating:

```
"{:#016x}".format(65536)
```